# AWS CloudFormation: EventBridge rule's event pattern is not formatted as needed

Tags: json, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I have this CloudFormation snippet for an AWS EventBridge Rule:

```
  AutoscalingRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: "AutoscalingRule"
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.autoscaling
        detail:
          - !Sub "AutoScalingGroupName: ${AutoscalingGroup}"
        detail-type:
          - "EC2 Instance Launch Successful"
          - "EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        -
          Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - "AutoscalingMonitoringLambda"
              - "Arn"
          Id: "autoscaling-monitoring"
```

The problem is that for **Event Pattern**, the **detail** section is not formatted as it should have been if created from the Console.
If created from the console, the **detail** section looks like this:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.autoscaling"],
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance Launch Successful", "EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"],
  "detail": {
    "AutoScalingGroupName": ["test"]
  }
}
```

but when deployed through CloudFormation it looks like this:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["EC2 Instance Launch Successful", "EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"],
  "source": ["aws.autoscaling"],
  "detail": ["AutoScalingGroupName: test"]
}
```

I have tried inserting it as JSON or formatting it manually but it doesn't work.

Any idea on how I should add the detail section to be the same as the one created in the Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "detail" section, in your Cloudformation template, is a YAML array, so it's traduced correctly in a JSON Array.

To fix it, change the EventPattern section to:

```
EventPattern:
    source:
      - aws.autoscaling
    detail:
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        - !Ref AutoscalingGroup
    detail-type:
      - "EC2 Instance Launch Successful"
      - "EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"
```

For further doubts on JSON -> YAML conversion, try: https://www.json2yaml.com/

Comment: I have tried but I get an error:
`Event pattern is not valid. Reason: "AutoScalingGroupName" must be an object or an array at [Source: (String)"{"detail-type":["EC2 Instance Launch Successful","EC2 Instance Terminate Successful"],"source":["aws.autoscaling"],"detail":{"AutoScalingGroupName":"test"}}"; line: 1, column: 150] (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidEventPatternException;`

Comment: How can I make it an object?

Comment: if "AutoscalingGroup" is another resource or a parameter in your template, change the !Sub "${AutoScalingGroup}" to !Ref AutoscalingGroup.

Comment: I get the same error: `Event pattern is not valid. Reason: "AutoScalingGroupName" must be an object or an array`

Comment: Ok, my bad, AutoScalingGroupName must be an array, so:
detail:
  AutoScalingGroupName:
    - !Ref AutoscalingGroup

Comment: I've updated the answer with the right syntax